# fail2ban not banning ssh bruteforce but regex works

Tags: ssh, brute-force

I've just noticed an SSH bruteforce at my server, which actually should have been banned by fail2ban, but for some reason it doesn't ban it. Most people who have problems with fail2ban, seem to have problems with their regex, which seems to be fine here.

part of **jail.conf**

```
[ssh]
enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
findtime = 6000
bantime = 86400
```

**fail2ban-client status ssh**

```
Status for the jail: ssh
|- filter
|  |- File list:    /var/log/auth.log 
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  `- Total failed: 0
`- action
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |  `- IP list:   
   `- Total banned: 0
```

**fail2ban-regex  /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf**

```
Running tests
=============

Use regex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf
Use log file   : /var/log/auth.log


Results
=======

Failregex
|- Regular expressions:
|  [1] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S
+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*(?:error: PAM: )?Authentication failure for .* from <HOST>\s*$
|  [2] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S
+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*(?:error: PAM: )?User not known to the underlying authentication module for .* from <HOST>\s*$
|  [3] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S
+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*Failed (?:password|publickey) for .* from <HOST>(?: port \d*)?(?: ssh\d*)?$
|  [4] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S
+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*ROOT LOGIN REFUSED.* FROM <HOST>\s*$
|  [5] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S
+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .* from <HOST>\s*$
|  [6] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S
+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers$
|  [7] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S
+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*authentication failure; logname=\S* uid=\S* euid=\S* tty=\S* ruser=\S* rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=.*)?\s*$
|  [8] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S
+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*refused connect from \S+ \(<HOST>\)\s*$
|  [9] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S
+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*Address <HOST> .* POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!*\s*$
|  [10] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\
S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups\s*$
|
`- Number of matches:
   [1] 0 match(es)
   [2] 0 match(es)
   [3] 380 match(es)
   [4] 0 match(es)
   [5] 353 match(es)
   [6] 26 match(es)
   [7] 0 match(es)
   [8] 0 match(es)
   [9] 0 match(es)
   [10] 0 match(es)

Ignoreregex
|- Regular expressions:
|
`- Number of matches:

Summary
=======

Addresses found:
[1]
[2]
[3]
    198.245.50.151 (Sat Dec 21 15:18:12 2013)
    198.245.50.151 (Sat Dec 21 15:18:15 2013)
    198.245.50.151 (Sat Dec 21 15:18:18 2013)
    198.245.50.151 (Sat Dec 21 15:18:21 2013)
    198.245.50.151 (Sat Dec 21 15:18:24 2013)
..................
Date template hits:
23379 hit(s): MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second Year
..................

Success, the total number of match is 759
```

Any ideas, why fail2ban does not ban, even if I have lots of regex matches?

Answer (score 33):

This question is pretty old, but I encountered the same problem, and after many many searches, finally found the solution.

My problem was due to a change on my Timezone: some time ago, I used the following command to set my correct timezone.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

My system time was ok, but the times of entries in auth.log were indeed shifted. And this was the problem for fail2ban: it has to compare entries of auth.log to check if it has to ban, keep, or unban... and logged entries were always considered as too old because of wrong time.

I just had to restart syslog daemon with:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Then, times were not any more shifted in auth.log, and fail2ban did its job successfully.

I hope this will help!

Comment: I guess that syslog is not able to adapt to new timezone unless it's restarted.
Indeed, this is what I noticed: the date/times of entries in auth.log (generated by syslog) were wrong until I restart syslog.

Answer (score 10):

I tried all the solutions here before I Googled it again and found the answer on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/597832/fail2ban-not-working-on-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-why#answer-597854):

Running `service rsyslog restart` was all I needed to do and now it works as expected (of course there's the possibility that all the solutions here were necessary as well...).  Unlike the poster of this question, I never deleted or edited the log file, so why this is the solution I know not.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, this is not an official solution but it does work:

3 months working perfectly until fail2ban upgraded and stopped banning. I can tell how hard I investigated to solve this issue and at the end this is the only way that works.

This should work

```
 sudo service fail2ban stop
 sudo service fail2ban start
```

This will not work

```
sudo service fail2ban restart
```

IMPORTANT: Test with another device (3G cell) an intentional failed ssh logging to verify fail2ban is working. If not, service stop/start again. Sometimes some jails don't load correctly. Never trust!!!!!

EXTRA NOTES:

- Using jail.local
- 4 jails enabled: ssh, dovecot, apache and wootwoot
- All jails working as a charm for months with no issue
- Ubuntu server 14.04
- fail2ban 0.9

Answer (score 5):

often when I have this trouble (on Debian boxes) it's something related to tzdata and wrong time. If the regexp works (and it's working) the only things that can prevent fai2ban from trggering is something screwed up with date/time. Try to install ntp and keep in sync your date.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. An NTP client was running on the box and at least /var/log/auth.log and /var/log/fail2ban.log use the same timezone. But you might be right, I'll try searching for time zone issues.

Comment: Had the same problem with an __owncloud 9__, date format was the culprit indeed. It was set to _UTC_ in owncloud's config file.

Answer (score 4):

Fail2ban not banning and regexp matching a lot? It's probably that your jail is missing a ban action. You have two options:

Option 1) 
Inside your jail [ssh] include

```
[ssh]
enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
action = %(action_mwl)s # <<== THIS IS FOR BANNING
maxretry = 6
findtime = 6000
bantime = 86400
```

Option 2)
Include a global action for all your jails just writing this (example)

```
# Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with the
# interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in jail.local
# globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section
action = %(action_mwl)s

[ssh]
    enabled  = true
    port     = ssh
    filter   = sshd
    logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
    maxretry = 6
    findtime = 6000
    bantime = 86400
```

BTW, at the top of jail.conf I can read a recommendation for using jail.local instead of jail.conf. May be it could be helpful to follow their instructions:

```
To avoid merges during upgrades DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE
# and rather provide your changes in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar behavior on a Ubuntu raring (13.04) box. Fail2ban was failing to notice changes in the */var/log/auth.log* file.
Changing the `backend` value in the *jail.conf* file did not change anything.

I finally fixed this up by installing the latest version of Fail2ban using the Backport builds are available from NeuroDebian as described on the [download page](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Downloads) from the Fail2ban website.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this is because the `__bsd_syslog_verbose` is wrong. fail2ban expects /var/log/auth.log to start with `YYYY.MM.DD` (ie: 2014.10.15) yet the logs read `MMM DD` (ie: Oct 15)

To fix this you will need to do the following:

```
cp /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.conf /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.local
```

Edit `common.local` and set:

```
__bsd_syslog_verbose = (<[^.]+ [^.]+>)
```

Restart fail2ban :

Ubuntu (don't use restart):

```
sudo service fail2ban stop
sudo service fail2ban start
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found it necessary to reboot my server before changes to sshd's port went into effect ... changing ports is pretty effective and simple.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (fail2ban 1.0.2 installed manually, Centos 7) the same issue was resolved by setting `backend = auto` instead of `backend = systemd`. This setting should be somewhere in your `jail.conf` or `jail.local` file.
Hope this will help somebody.